# How compatible is Chau Chee Yang's dbExpress and XE2 Enterprise dbExpress for Firebird?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, dbexpress

I use Delphi 2010 Professional which did not come with the dbExpress driver for Firebird. If I start using the Firebird [dbExpress driver written by Chau Chee Yang](https://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/) and then later upgrade to XE?? Enterprise (which comes with the Firebird dbExpress driver) will the code just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lists support for delphi XE2 in the 34 version changelog

> "Support Delphi XE2"

So it should work also you could ask on the dbxfirebird group for more info https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dbxfirebird